# Xamarin Drag and drop how to edit balloon icon and text see image

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

Using the drag drop sample https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/WorkingWithGestures/DragAndDropGesture
I'm not sure its actually a notify balloon not sure of its correct terminology making it hard to search. In the image you can see when drop location is active it displays in the ballon the copy icon and copy as text. I want to change the icon and the text but not sure how.
I have tried the following code but it doesn't do anything.

```
private void OnCorrectDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Data.Text = "My text data goes here";
        e.Data.Image = "plusicon.png";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add the corresponding `xaml`?  `… DragOver="OnCorrectDragOver" …`. Did you read drag and drop doc, where it discusses dragover?

Comment: This is an internal command and currently can't be changed per Microsoft. See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/840152/xamarin-drag-and-drop-notification-icon-ant-text.html?childToView=841643#answer-841643

Comment: That's a shame. I considered trying to fake it - put something "in front of" the monkey - but I think the dragged image is always on top. Maybe make visible an image and text that appears on-screen a bit higher than the target rectangle. Not ideal, but at least its something.